# Java builder pattern - abstract builder

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, builder-pattern

First of all, I'm relatively new to Java, so may be what I am asking is trivial, but I could not find an answer here or in other place.

For simplicity, let's assume I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Shape {
    protected Shape(double x, double y) {...}
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    public Circle(double radius) {...}
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle(double edge) {...}
}
```

I'd like to use a builder pattern for each shape. So I added Builders to each one of them:

```
class Shape {
    protected static abstract class BuilderBase<T extends BuilderBase<T, S>, S extends Shape> {
        public T setLocation(double x, double y) {
            // ...
            return (T)this; // ? - is there a way to avoid this casting?
        }

        public abstract S build();
    }

    protected Shape(/*...*/) {/*...*/}
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    public static class Builder extends BuilderBase<Builder, Circle> {
        public Builder setRadius(double radius) {
            //...
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Circle build() { return new Circle(/*...*/); }
    }

    private Circle(/*...*/) {/*...*/}
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public static class Builder extends BuilderBase<Builder, Rectangle> {
        public Builder setRadius(double radius) {
            //...
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Rectangle build() { 
            return new Rectangle(/*...*/); 
        }
    }

    public Rectangle(/*...*/) {/*...*/}
}
```

**EDIT:**
Generic here was used in order to allow using Builder methods in any order. For example, in order to allow the following call:

```
new Circle.Builder()
    .setLocation(0, 0)
    .setRadius(10)
    .build();
```

My problem is in this casting:

```
public T setLocation(double x, double y) {
    // ...
    return (T)this; // ? - is there a way to avoid this casting?
}
```

I'm struggling to find a way to avoid this casting. The only way I found till now was to add yet another abstract method to the BaseBuilder method:

```
protected static abstract class BuilderBase<T extends BuilderBase<T, S>, S extends Shape> {
    protected abstract T getBuilder();

    public T setLocation(double x, double y) {
        // ...
        return getBuilder();
    }

    //...
}
```

So each derived builder will have to implement it:

```
@Override
protected Circle getBuilder() { 
    return this; 
}
```

It seems to me as overkill but I don't want to get compilation warnings.

**Question:** is there any more elegant way to avoid the casting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t avoid having a little bit of additional code per subclass but you can avoid having an unchecked cast. Just create an `abstract` method responsible for returning an appropriately typed `this`. This method has to be implemented by concrete subclasses once but can be used for all methods of the base class which ought to return `this`:

```
class Shape {
  protected static abstract
  class BuilderBase<T extends BuilderBase<T, S>, S extends Shape> {
    /** all subclasses should implement {@code self()} as {@code return this;} */
    abstract T self();
    public T setLocation(double x, double y) {
        // ...
        return self();
    }
    public T setFooBar(FooBar x) {
      // ...
      return self();// the more methods you have the more useful self() becomes
  }

    public abstract S build();
  }

  protected Shape(/*...*/) {/*...*/}
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  public static class Builder extends BuilderBase<Builder, Circle> {
    @Override final Builder self() { return this; }

    public Builder setRadius(double radius) {
        //...
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Circle build() { return new Circle(/*...*/); }
  }

  private Circle(/*...*/) {/*...*/}
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
  public static class Builder extends BuilderBase<Builder, Rectangle> {
    @Override final Builder self() { return this; }

    public Builder setRadius(double radius) {
      //...
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle build() { 
      return new Rectangle(/*...*/); 
    }
  }

  public Rectangle(/*...*/) {/*...*/}
}
```

Comment: @Arkadiy: An *unchecked* cast vs. some trivial, easy to prove correct, methods. There *are* developers preferring a bit more but easier to maintain code over lesser but harder to maintain code. From a performance point of view the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: I have to admit that @Holger's way is safer as it catches the situations like `class ScrewedUpBuilder extends BuilderBase<CircleBuilder>`.

Comment: Then again, the use of ScrewedUpBuilder would catch this problem compile-time: you look to chain a ScrewedUpBuilder method and the compiler tells you that it does not exist in CircleBuilder.

Comment: @Holger, Actually, your solution is the same as appears in the question itself. Just in the question it is called as `getBuilder()` instead of `self()`. Although, I must say that name `self()` is much more fitting here. I just was wonder whether there is simpler way of doing this

Comment: @Denis Itskovich: I didn’t notice your solution in the question when I wrote my answer. Well, the answer is that Java Generics don’t have a way to declare such a relationship between the type of `this` and a type parameter. Even the core classes suffer from that, e.g. `Comparable<T>`— if there was a way to declare that `T` ought to be the actual type implementing `Comparable`, i.e. its comparable to itself, it was declared using that way…

Comment: @Holger what is the problem regarding an unchecked cast? Any scenario?

Comment: @Weishi Zeng: an unchecked cast may be fine or even unavoidable in some scenarios, but you won’t notice, if you are wrong as that’s why these casts are called *unchecked*. So if there is a simple way to avoid it, you should use it. If the solution is not that simple, well, then it’s a trade-off. Here, it was the actual question, how to avoid it.